# Finding the Dictator in Arrow's Impossibility Theorem

Tags: algorithms, computer-science, economics, algorithmic-game-theory, social-choice-theory

[Arrow's Impossibility Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrow%27s_impossibility_theorem) states that if we have at least three different social states and a finite number of individuals (voters), any social welfare function that satisfies the conditions of universal domain (*U*), independence of irrelevant alternatives (*IIA*), and the Pareto principle (*PP*) must have a dictator.

Given a social welfare function that respects *U, IIA*, and *PP*, and a social profile (a set of individual preferences), how would one find the dictator? What is the most efficient algorithm to do so? Has anyone looked into the computational complexity of this?

Comment: There is no perfect algorithm, since if I happen to be a sycophant of the dictator, and happen to have the exact same preferences, you could not distinguish me from the dictator.

Comment: However, for each result produced by the function, you can eliminate those individuals who have a differing preference from contention of being the dictator.

Comment: Can you clarify _exactly_ what data your algorithm is given?  I am not entirely sure what you mean but for every interpretation I can think of the question is totally trivial...

Comment: If you've got a black box which implements the algorithm then it is easy...have people vote in thirds, assuming there are exactly three options (or in sixths if you can get at the full ranking).  Obviously the dictator is in the group with the winning choice.  Now divide that group into thirds (or sixths) , and so on.  If you have different data then this, you should explain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The social welfare function ranks the $n$ available alternatives as $x_1 \succ x_2 \succ x_3 \succ \ldots \succ x_n$.

Every agent whose ranking over the available alternatives matches the social ranking is a "dictator".

Note that "dictator" in Arrow's theorem does not necessarily mean that that person decides the social ranking. As far as the individual and the society have the same ranking, that person is indistinguishable from a dictator.

Comment: Thanks, this is precisely what I was missing.